# TypeError: string indices must be integers Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my Pandas dataframe

```
#df1:

  col1  col2    col3
0   a   1.0     1.0
1   a   2.0     2.0
2   b   3.0     3.0
3   b   NaN     4.0
4   a   5.0     5.0
```

I am trying to write a function to get the rows based on col2>2:

```
def colreturn(datarow):
    if datarow['col2']>2:
        return datarow['col2']
    else:
        return ''
```

It is throwing error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

However, I am able to do it in the dataframe itself:

```
df1['col2'] = np.where(df1['col2']>1, df1['col2'], '')
df1
```

Please help.

Comment: You're looking for output similar to `df1[df1['col2'] > 2] `?

Comment: Or, if you dont want to filter `df.col2.where(df.col2 > 0)`

Comment: Also how are you _calling_ the function. The error implies that `datarow` is a string not a dataframe.

Comment: @HenryEcker, calling the function - df1['col2'] = df1.applymap(colreturn)
df2